# Make call by click on Button

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I writing app for Windows Phone 10

I try to make phone call by pressing a button like this

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("phone number", "display name");
```

But have this error:

> Error CS1069  The type name 'PhoneCallManager' could not be found in
>   the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls'. This type has been
>   forwarded to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>   ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a reference to that
>   assembly.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Say if it helped or not, mark the answer or say what did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that you are using a different namespace (`Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls`). The answer is in the error. It is recommending you to include a different assembly, meaning `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract`

Edit: As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.showphonecallui), I would recommend checking the requirements, there might be something you have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had that error and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36825157/426227):

> You have to include Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP. Just add a new reference and go into Univerval Windows/Extensions.