# UWP - class PhoneLine not found

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make phone calls from my application. I'm supposed to use `PhoneLine` from namespace `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls;`. But `PhoneLine` is not in `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls;`, however according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn297266) it should be there. When I add it to source code like `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneLine` this and hover over it, there is a hint saying:

`The type name 'PhoneLine' could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublickKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.`

So I tried to access `PhoneLine` through `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract'`, but VS says that `PhoneLine` does not exist in `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` eighter.

I have checked `Phone Call` and `VOIP Calls` in app manifest with no success. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include **Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP**. Just add a new reference and go into Univerval Windows/Extensions.

If needed, you can find the following sample on github :  https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PhoneCall

Comment: I've checkout the sample already. It should have occurred to me that PhoneLine is device specific